# c# Starting events with hotkey?

Tags: c#, events, hotkeys, beep

```
    private void MeretOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code
    }

    private void MeretTB_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        {
            MeretOK_Click();
        }
    }
```

How can I start an event with a hotkey?
(I know I can just copy the code there but that is ugly)
If I just copy the code and run it I hear a beep. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to allow your form to handle key events globally (set the form `KeyPreview` property to `true`) and to mark your event as internally handled. Second, if the purpose of this code is to simulate the mouse click on a specific control (`programmatic click`), for example a button, there is an easier way to accomplish it:

```
private void MeretTB_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        myButton.PerformClick();
    }
}
```